# Any way to grab all Twitter handles in the USA?

Tags: api, twitter, data-analysis, handle

I'm interested in finding patterns in Twitter handles across all 50 states.

Have looked around the Twitter api but there doesn't seem to be an endpoint for this type of functionality. Can get tweets from a particular handle.

Has anyone ever tried anything like this, not really sure what else to try here.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: no, there is no way to pull this data from Twitter. I could set my location to “on the Moon” and the API sould not have an endpoint to get the data anyway.